# All bone charms appear in Corvo's room?

Tags: dishonored

For some reason once I finish the part where you get your first rune and your blink power, about 10 bone charms along with some statuettes (the ones that increase your max bone charms) appear in Corvo's room. Is this a known bug? This is happening on a fresh save file.

Comment: There are several dozens bone charms within the game.  I seriously doubt every single one is in Corvo's room.  Can we get this question revised to be more accurate of the actual situation?

Comment: I wasn't aware that there were so many. To me, it seemed like that was ever single one (This is my first time playing the game).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you preordered Dishonored with **'Arkcane Assassin Pack'** (from Gamestop) and/or **'Back Street Butcher Pack'** (from Amazon), you get access to 6 special bone charms, available in Corvo's room.

> ```
> Void Channel: Corvo's supernatural abilities last longer and do more damage
> Gutter Feast: When Corvo eats a white rat, he regains mana.
> White Rat Friend: White rats are neutral towards Corvo, not hostile. 
> Fencer: Win sword vs. sword contest more frequently.
> Blast Resistant: Damage from explosions reduced slightly.
> Fire Water: Shot whiskey bottles explode with greater intensity.
> ```

source : [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dishonored/Bone_Charms)

**EDIT:**

just found out about some other charms that appear in Corvo's bedroom [HERE](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Whalebone_Charms).

Comment: edited my answer a bit, found out about some more charms :D

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to disable these bonuses? I'm playing on PC for a Let's Play, and I don't want any of this crap in the video.

Comment: hum, about the dunwall city trials, just do a fresh install of the game and don't download that. Amazon/Gamestop related bonus i don't think, if you claimed a key (just guessing) they will be available when you install. Include them in the Let's play and explain what they are :)

Comment: Those are actually only 2 out of 4 pre-order packages. The 'DLC' listed on the wiki page is all 4 sets of preorder bonuses. Dunwall City Trials has nothing to do with it. Each includes 3 Bone Charms. Most of them range from totally useless flavor to mildly useful. None are a particularly big deal.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz thanks, edited my answer to remove my faulty assumption :)

Comment: I'm not in a position to write up an edit at the moment, but I think this answer is still misleading in that it does not separate the 4 various DLC's. It also doesn't seem to fully or properly address the question, as if the asker is seeing more than 3 charms, there is clearly some sort of bug involved.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo In the PS3 version main menu, you can view installed DLC and delete it directly from there, I don't know if it's the same on your version, but that's an alternative to a full reinstall...